# css prepend host to absolute path. How to avoid?

Tags: css

I need to pass font by absolute path to a css file, but host is automatically prepended to the url.

For example:
**/var/www/myproject/public/fonts/myfont.oft** 
become 
**http://myhost.local/var/www/myproject/public/fonts/myfont.oft**
How can I avoid this behavior?

I found a solution but it's not valid in all context. 
I'm using laravel, and I have a route registered to root path so I can pass to css this string: 
URL::to('/') . "/fonts/myfont.otf"

Comment: Try removing the first `/` from the url

Comment: why do you need to use the absolute path, you are able to do it as a relative path but it must be relative to the css file - not the webpage

Comment: removing '/' i've a relative path. I need an absolute path because the css is a php file that generate dynamic css and it is included in each view of the project. So for the browser i'm using inline css and the path is relative to the view.

Answer (score 0):

use

`//fonts.yourfontwebhost.com/var/www/myproject/public/fonts/myfont.oft`

It is generally preferable to omit the `http` in front of the `//`.

Comment: the problem is that i don't want to specify manually the hostname or i need to change when i move the project from local to production machine